# Issue in using managers

Tags: blackberry

I want to dispaly some data at the top of the screen and some at the end of the screen,creating two different managers,the issue is after running i cannot see any data on the screen

```
  public NativeScreen() {


           super();
               LabelField title = new LabelField("Calendar DatePicker",
                               LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

              hrzManager = new HorizontalFieldManager() {
                    protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {
                            graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x0007F5ED);
                               graphics.clear();
                              super.paint(graphics);
                 }
              };
             hrzManager.add(title);   


      VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManagerUpper = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | 
      Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH ) ;  
      verticalFieldManagerUpper.add(hrzManager);    
     //Add the manager to the screen.
     this.add(verticalFieldManagerUpper);

    VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | 
        Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH ) ;


    HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);

    ImageButtonField bitmapField = new ImageButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("pimdemo_jde.png"),  Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);
    horizontalFieldManager.add(bitmapField);
    ImageButtonField bitmapField1 = new ImageButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("attachmentdemo_jde.png"), Field.FIELD_BOTTOM);
    horizontalFieldManager.add(bitmapField1);

    //Add the fields to the manager.
    verticalFieldManager.add(horizontalFieldManager);

    //Add the manager to the screen.
    this.add(verticalFieldManager);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the set status and set title -

```
setTitle(field);
setStatus(field);
```